# Different Ways of Creating Class Method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, methods, syntax, class-method

Example 1:

```
class Dog
  def self.class_method
    :another_way_to_write_class_methods
  end
end

def test_you_can_use_self_instead_of_an_explicit_reference_to_dog
  assert_equal :another_way_to_write_class_methods, Dog.class_method
end
```

Example 2:

```
class Dog
  class << self
    def another_class_method
      :still_another_way
    end
  end
end

def test_heres_still_another_way_to_write_class_methods
  assert_equal :still_another_way, Dog.another_class_method
end
```

May I know which way of writing the class method is preferred in Ruby and why? Are there situations where one is preferred over another?

Comment: you can also write `def Dog.class_method;end` which you can also write outside of the class block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[this ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) says  the `class << self` syntax is "possible and convenient when you have to define many class methods."

They have code examples using both versions, so there's definitely not a broad community consensus for using one over the other.

I personally use `def self.my_method` to minimize indentation

Answer (score 6):

You asked for different ways to create class methods. Here are some.

```
class A
  def self.a
    "A"
  end
end
A.a #=> "A"
```

---

```
class B
  class << self
    def b
      "B"
    end
  end
end
B.b #=> "B"
```

---

```
class C
  singleton_class.class_eval do
    def c
      "C"
    end
  end
end
C.c #=> "C"
```

---

```
module M
  def m
    "M"
  end
end

class D
  extend M
end
D.m #=> "M"
```

---

```
class E
  class << self
    include M
  end
end
E.m #=> "M"
```

---

```
class F
  singleton_class.instance_eval do
    define_method(:f) do
      "F"
    end
  end
end
F.f #=> "F"
```

If `:f` is to be created dynamically,

```
class F
end
F.singleton_class.instance_eval do
   define_method(:f) do
     "F"
   end
end
```

or a variant:

```
F.singleton_class.instance_eval "define_method(:f) { 'F' }"
F.f #=> "F"
```

---

```
class Class
  def k
    "K"
  end
end

class G
end
G.k #=> "K"
```

The problem here is that all instance methods of `Class` (including `:k`) are available for use as (class) methods by all classes, because classes are instances of `Class` (`H.class#=>Class`).

---

```
class Object
  def o
    "O"
  end
end

class H
end
H.o #=> "O"
H.new.o #=> "O"
```

This one is interesting. `Object` is an ancestor of `Class` (`Class.ancestors #=> [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`), so `Class` inherits the instance method `:o` from `Object`. Hence (from the previous case), `:o` is a class method of `H`. However, `H` is also a subclass of `Object` (`H.superclass #=> Object`), so `H` inherits the instance method `Object#:o`.

---

As to which is "best", it depends. If just a few class methods are to be created, most would use `A`. If a large number were needed, I would use `D` or `B`. If class methods were to be created dynamically, `F`, or some variant. I can't imagine a situation, however, where I would use `G` or `H`.